# Call layout from another class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

Here I've called layout from another class and snippet as follows

```
class example extends Activity{
      class2 btn;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.main);       
           btn.color(); 
      }
}
//Another class(class2)
public class class2 extends Activity{
    protected void color(){
      View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
          LinearLayout layoutcolor=(LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.linearcolor); 
     //some code
   }
}
```

How can I call layout id in class2 by that I can display it from class example above code floods error.

Comment: what are you trying to achive with this ?

Comment: need to call layout id from another class as I tried above

Comment: So you need to update the layout or just generate the layout and show?

Comment: Actually am using example class and main.xml layout. In that class calling another class function -- there am calling main.xml/r.id (calling layout inside main.xml) and displaying its works in example class

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What errors are you getting. Why are you not posting that. If the error is posted, atleast answering your question is easier. Else you expect people to compile your code for you ?

Comment: +1, "Your question is very unclear."

Answer (score -1):

```
class example extends Activity {
    class2 btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = new Class2();
        btn.color(this);
    }
}

// Another class(class2)
public class class2 {
    protected void color(Activity mActivity) {
        LinearLayout layoutcolor = (LinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.linearcolor);
        // some code
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I created a sample and it works for me, just check your implementation. OR post full code.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class sampleMediaPlayer extends ListActivity {
    // Toast mToast;

    private TextView selection;

    class2 btn;
    private static final String[] items = { "Computer Hardware", "Featured", "Information Technology",
            "Software", "Technical"

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        btn = new class2();
        btn.color(this);

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        selection.setText(items[position]);
    }

    // Another class(class2)
    public class class2 {
        protected void color(Activity mActivity) {
            ListView layoutcolor = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            layoutcolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Log.i("NIMISH", "HEy ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this was expected to work ? the class2 constructor is missing.

Comment: ever heard of default constructor ?